# VxWorks change console port while running

Tags: vxworks, rtos

Is there any way to change the console port on an iMX6 running VxWorks 7 while running? I know how to change it via kernel configuration, but that is a compile time setting. Is there any way I can change it while running?

Answer (score 1):

The [ioLib documentation](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/ioLib.html) explains how to redirect the stdio file descriptors at run-time either globally or on a per task basis, using `ioGlobalStdSet()`  or `ioTaskStdSet()` respectively.  You can set  stdin, stout, and stderr independently, so you will need to set all three to redirect *all* console I/O.

So for example:

```
#include <ioLib.h>

int redirectStdio( const char* devname )
{
    int new_io_fd = open( devname, O_RDWR, 0 ) ;

    if( new_io_fd >= 0 )
    {
        ioGlobalStdSet( STD_IN, new_io_fd ) ;
        ioGlobalStdSet( STD_OUT, new_io_fd ) ;
        ioGlobalStdSet( STD_ERR, new_io_fd ) ;
    }
    return new_io_fd ;
}
```

Then you might have:

```
if( redirectStdio( "/tyCo/2" ) < 0 )
{
    printf( "Redirect failed - still here!\n" ) ;
}
else
{
    printf( "stdio now directs here\n" ) ;
}
```

There are also `ioGlobalStdGet()` and `ioTaskStdGet()` functions so it is possible to retain the original settings and restore them if necessary for example.

Comment: Note that this answer was formulated from reading the documentation; I have not used VxWorks in years and have no means of testing the above.  Try it and add comment if there are any problems.